# À quoi le mot « saloir » fait-il référence dans ce cas ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

Le mot « saloir » fait référence à quoi dans la phrase suivante :

« Petit! Petit! qu'il sursaute!... Mais dis donc chnok! (*sic*) Je peux pas en croquer comme un autre? Ah! **Saloir**! Salut! Puisque c'est la guerre! » (*Guignol's Band*)

C'est dans le milieu de la prostitution.

Est-ce une référence à l'expression  « mettre la viande au saloir » ? non ?

Comme l'expression est datée de 1969/1977 selon le TLF, et *Guignol's Band* paraît en 1944, je n'en suis pas sûr.

Comment: « *Dessaler* :  rendre  moins  niais,  plus  dégourdi ;  se 
dessaler : se dégourdir, se déniaiser. » https://www.langue-francaise.org/conference_Thouvenin_Argot_expose.pdf. “Dessaler une morue” : déniaiser une fille pour en faire une gagneuse (son gagne-pain) … *Au saloir*, se retirer pour un temps du tapin pour vivre tranquillement.

Comment: @Personne Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a rien de sûr dans l'interprétation que je propose, mais elle pourrait bien être la clé de cette énigme.

Il existe une expression d'argot, « *mettre la viande au saloir* », qui signifie « se coucher ».  ([Encyclopédie Universelle](https://encyclopedie_universelle.fr-academic.com/67494/saloir), voir aussi [Expressions Françaises](https://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-m/874-mettre-la-viande-dans-un-torchon.html))

Comme ce qui suit « Saloir ! » est « Salut ! », c'est à dire une formule de politesse qui signifie « au revoir », le tout correspondrait  à « je vais me coucher, au revoir », ce qui est une suite assez logique ; cela serait  une façon de dire « j'arrête là, je ne discute plus ». Cependant, si cela semble assez plausible, rien ne permet d'assurer que Céline code  la forme entière « Je mets la viande au saloir » dans le simple énoncé  « saloir », bien que le procédé de raccourcissement et d'identification que cela implique soit assez courant chez lui.

Comment: Merci ! La datation de l'expression en argot dans le TLF (qui est postérieure à la publication du roman) ne pose pas un problème, à votre avis ?

Comment: @ovide Ce qui semble le plus probable c'est que l'usage n'apparait pas encore dans la langue écrite lorsque Céline rédige Guignol's Band, ce qui n'empêche pas Céline de le connaitre puisque avant qu'un terme soit attesté un certain nombre d'années doivent s'écouler pendant lesquelles il se répand dans la population ; il est peu probable qu'il se soit soucié de n'employer que des termes vérifiés.

Comment: Merci beaucoup !